# Coordinates For A 5-Pointed Star In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

What I'm trying to do is draw a 5 pointed star. I got the coordinates but I believe I'm missing the width and height. I'm on the right track because I tested the program using code to output a rectangle, which was pretty simple. the code was

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

But for a 5 pointed star I just don't know what the width and height should be. I'd appreciate any help.
Here it is:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Imaging" %>
     <script runat="server">
     void 
     Page_Load()
     {
     Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
     Response.Clear();
     Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(151, 151);
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);
     g.Clear(Color.White);
     Point[] points = {
     new Point(28, 0), new Point(495, 55), new Point(514, 55), 
     new Point(520,40), new Point(526, 55), new Point(550, 55), 
     new Point(530, 65), new Point(540,85), new Point(520, 72), 
     new Point(500, 85), new Point(510, 65), new Point(495,55)};
     g.DrawLines(new Pen(Color.Black), points);
     bitmap1.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     bitmap1.Dispose();
     g.Dispose();
     Response.Flush();
     }
     </script>
```

Screen shot [image]

Comment: Find your max `x` and max `y`

Comment: i think you need two points with same height at bottom. two with same higher height at middle . and one with higher height and at 0 width.

Comment: What do you mean find my max(x, y)? I thought the pared (28, 0) were it. Hold on. Do you mean that I have to give a dimension to w and h to correspond to the x and y coordinates. So that would be same width and height all around. I'll try it and get back with you. This may be easier than I thought.

Comment: 'System.Drawing.Point' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments. I guess that didn't work. What I did was (28,0,10,10); But it worked with the rectangle. Why? And why not with the Star shape I'm trying to create?

Comment: Try to use these points and draw lines in order...`Point(0, 60), Point(30, 0), Point(-30, 30), Point(30, 30), Point(-30, 0), Point(0,60)`

Comment: I tried those coordinates and what I got is edited in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already works as it is. You just need to use a convenient array of points. For intance, for a 150x150 bitmap:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Clear();
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(150, 150);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        Point[] points = {
            new Point(75,0),
            new Point(150,150),
            new Point(0,50),
            new Point(150,50),
            new Point(0,150),
            new Point(75,0)
         };
        g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);
        bitmap1.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bitmap1.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        Response.Flush();
    }
```

[image]